# "Place dots" in HTML/CSS/JS slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make a slideshow with those little navigation or placeholder dots along the bottom - the slideshow itself is working, but in the minimal example here, there's only one dot showing up at the bottom. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - researched, left it for a couple days and came back to it, now time for a question...

Here's the code I'm working with:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style>
                html {
                    background-color: lightblue;
                }
                body {
                    width:1024px;
                    height:768px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    border-style: solid;
                    background: lightgreen;
                    position: relative;
                }
                div#banner{
                    position: absolute;
                    top:50px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 120px;
                    background: pink;
                    text-align: center;
                    padding-top: 0px;
                    padding-bottom: 0px;
                    font-size:1.5em;
                }
                div#minibanner{
                    position: absolute;
                    top:0px;
                    height:50px;
                    width: 100%;
                    background: orange;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                div#slideContainer {
                    position:absolute;
                    left:200px;
                    top:170px;
                    height:558px;
                    width:794px;
                    padding-top: 30px;
                    padding-left:30px;
                    font-size: 2em;
                    background: yellow;
                }
                div#sidenav{
                    position: absolute;
                    top:170px;
                    left:0px;
                    width: 200px;
                    height:558px;
                }
                .contentSlide{
                    display: none;
                }
                div#bottomnav{
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom:0px;
                    height:40px;
                    width: 100%;
                    background: pink;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .dot {
                  position:absolute;
                  bottom:60px;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  height: 15px;
                  width: 15px;
                  margin: 22px 22px; 
                  background-color: #bbb;
                  border-radius: 50%;
                  display: inline-block; 
                  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
                }
                .active, .dot:hover {
                  background-color: #717171;
                }
                .fade {
                  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
                  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
                  animation-name: fade;
                  animation-duration: 1.5s;
                }
                @-webkit-keyframes fade {
                  from {opacity: .4} 
                  to {opacity: 1}
                }
                
                @keyframes fade {
                  from {opacity: .4} 
                  to {opacity: 1}
                }
                .prev, .next {
                  cursor: pointer;
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 50%;
                  width: auto;
                  padding: 16px;
                  margin-top: -22px;
                  color: red;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  font-size: 18px;
                  transition: 0.6s ease;
                  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
                  user-select: none;
                }
                .next {
                  right: 0;
                  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
                }
                .prev {
                    left:0;
                }
                .prev:hover, .next:hover {
                  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="minibanner"><h3>Title of Presentation: testing, testing testing</h3></div>
            <div id="banner"><h1>Introduction</h1></div>
            <div id="sidenav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../../index.html">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Introduction</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Section 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Section 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Section 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Conclusion</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="slideContainer">
                <div class="contentSlide fade">
                    <p>Here's an outline:
                        <ul>
                            <li>Introduction</li>
                            <li>Section 1</li>
                            <li>Section 2</li>
                            <li>Section 3</li>
                            <li>Conclusion</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="contentSlide fade">
                    <p>Here are some themes:
                        <ul>
                            <li>Theme 1</li>
                            <li>Theme 2</li>
                            <li>Theme 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>            
                <div class="contentSlide fade">
                    <p>...and the conclusions:
                        <ul>
                            <li>Conclusion A</li>
                            <li>Conclusion B</li>
                            <li>Conclusion C</li>
                            <li>Conclusion D</li>
                            <li>Conclusion E</li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center">
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
            </div>
            <div id="bottomnav"><p>footer</p></div>
            <script>
                var slideIndex = 1;
                showSlides(slideIndex);                
                // Next/previous controls
                function plusSlides(n) {
                    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
                }
                // Thumbnail image controls
                function currentSlide(n) {
                    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
                }
                function showSlides(n) {
                    var i;
                    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("contentSlide");
                    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1;} 
                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length;}
                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                    }
                    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
                    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Anybody have an idea where the first two dots are and  how I can fix it so the three dots are in a row?

Answer (score 2):

Your dots (aka pips) have an absolute position so they're all going to overlap. Absolute positioning does exactly what it says and puts things at an exact position. It will ignore the normal "flow" that HTML typically does (also known as "has layout"), even though you've got them displaying as `inline-block`.

Instead, you should wrap them in a container element and position that accordingly. Then, the pips inside the container will "have layout" and flow side-by-side according to the `inline-block` display type.

Here's a basic working example

```css
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;

background: rebeccapurple;
}

.navigation {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;

  text-align: center; /* buttons align like text */
}

.pip {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.pip--active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="navigation">
    <button type="button" class="pip pip--active"></button>
    <button type="button" class="pip"></button>
    <button type="button" class="pip"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I've used buttons instead of links for the pips. This is because the pips don't actually link anywhere when clicked; They simply updates the state of the slideshow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have two missing dots; all your dots are sitting on top of each other!

You gave each dot `position: absolute`, but they didn't have separate `left` or `right` values, so they just ended up sitting on top of each other.

The solution to this is simple: make their parent `position: absolute` and let the dots just be `position: static`.

Once you do this, the other problem you'll notice is that the dots appear off-center to the left because they are positioned relative to the overall page, whereas you probably want them centered in the yellow area.

Moving the dots' wrapper inside `#slideContainer` will fix this problem because `#slideContainer` is also `position: absolute`, and absolute positioning works in relation to an element's nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., any element above it in the tree that is either `position: relative`, `position: absolute`, or `position: sticky`).

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("contentSlide");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

body {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  background: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
}

div#banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

div#minibanner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

div#slideContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 170px;
  height: 558px;
  width: 794px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: 2em;
  background: yellow;
}

div#sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 558px;
}

.contentSlide {
  display: none;
}

div#bottomnav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
}
.dots-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 22px 22px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="minibanner">
  <h3>Title of Presentation: testing, testing testing</h3>
</div>
<div id="banner">
  <h1>Introduction</h1>
</div>
<div id="sidenav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../../index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Section 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Conclusion</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="slideContainer">
  <div class="contentSlide fade">
    <p>Here's an outline:
      <ul>
        <li>Introduction</li>
        <li>Section 1</li>
        <li>Section 2</li>
        <li>Section 3</li>
        <li>Conclusion</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="contentSlide fade">
    <p>Here are some themes:
      <ul>
        <li>Theme 1</li>
        <li>Theme 2</li>
        <li>Theme 3</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="contentSlide fade">
    <p>...and the conclusions:
      <ul>
        <li>Conclusion A</li>
        <li>Conclusion B</li>
        <li>Conclusion C</li>
        <li>Conclusion D</li>
        <li>Conclusion E</li>
      </ul>
    </p>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  <div class="dots-wrapper" style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="bottomnav">
  <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Also for the explanation!!